Logic App (standard) deployment via DevOps pipeline - kudu service unavailable 503
When deploying a Logic App (standard) and the resource doesn't exist, approx every third deployment will fail with a "kudu service unavailable 503" error.
The deployment is done in two steps:
Infrastructure
ARM template is deployed using the AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 task.
The deployment is successful, however:

the App Service overview page displays "error" instead of the runtime version
kudu becomes unresponsive
the Log Stream is unavailable
In the activity log in the azure portal, there is a Validate action which fails with a message: “The gateway did not receive a response from ‘Microsoft.Web’ within the specified time period: 504"

Stopping/starting the app or changing the App Service Plan fixes this, and the ASP CPU/memory usage is near 0%, which seems to point to an unhandled runtime exception.
In the pipeline, if also deploying the application using AzureFunctionApp@1:

Within a few minutes Azure DevOps displays “No message found for this issue”
It may take up to 45 mins to deploy, or it may fail with the output below:

Starting: Deploying Standard Logic App

Task         : Azure Functions Deploy
Description  : Update a function app with .NET, Python, JavaScript, PowerShell, Java based web applications
Version      : 2.238.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azurefunctiontroubleshooting

Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'logicapp-dev'
NOTE: Function app is VNet integrated.
Deleting App Service Application settings. Data: ["WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP","WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"]
App Service Application settings are already present.
Validating deployment package for functions app before Zip Deploy
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://$logicapp-dev:***@logicapp-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Service Unavailable (CODE: 503)
##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Service Unavailable (CODE: 503)
App Service Application URL: https://logicapp-dev.azurewebsites.net
Finishing: Deploying Standard Logic App

Following the link to the kudu trace logs provides the following:
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Illegal characters in path.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)\r\n   
    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)\r\n   
    at Kudu.Services.Infrastructure.VfsControllerBase.GetOriginalLocalFilePath() 
    in C:\\__w\\1\\s\\Kudu.Services\\Infrastructure\\VfsControllerBase.cs:line 327\r\n   
    at Kudu.Services.Infrastructure.VfsControllerBase.GetLocalFilePath() 
    in C:\\__w\\1\\s\\Kudu.Services\\Infrastructure\\VfsControllerBase.cs:line 316\r\n   
    at Kudu.Services.Infrastructure.VfsControllerBase.GetItem() 
    in C:\\__w\\1\\s\\Kudu.Services\\Infrastructure\\VfsControllerBase.cs:line 52\r\n   
    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor
    
    ...continued...
}

I've spent about 5 days ruling out the following:

Application itself (workflows, connections, parameters, host.json etc)
API connections
App Service Plan (tried deleting + scaling up)
Application runtime (tried reverting from dotnet to Node)
ARM template (new logic app ARM template created in Azure Portal also fails)
Pipeline task (tried using AzureFunctionApp@2)
Logic App name (tried renaming the logic app and fileshare, initially succeeded in DEV/SIT then same error in UAT)
Storage Account Firewall (tried enabling public access)
Not deploying file share manually (deploying a Standard Logic App also provisions one automatically unless WEBSITE_SKIP_CONTENTSHARE_VALIDATION is set to 1)
Deleting deployments folder via Kudu (some users reported the residual files being there related to the connection between DevOps and Azure)

Notes:

Logic App is VNet integrated using a storage account in a separate resource group.
Storage account is configured with private endpoints and to allow access to Trusted Azure Services.
App Settings have WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING, WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET and WEBSITE_SKIP_CONTENTSHARE_VALIDATION configured (storage File Share is deployed first)
App Insights show no failures from the logic app to the storage account file share

Has anyone come across this kudu 503 error before when deploying a Logic App (standard) or Function App?

Go to the root directory of your logic app in kudu, check if there is an app_offline.html file exists. If so, delete it and then try the deployment again.

If deleting the app_offline.html file can work, I recommend you try to use the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 - Azure App Service deploy v4 task to deploy your logic app. This task has an option called TakeAppOfflineFlag (Take App Offline), you can set its value to false on the task. Then the deployment will not place the app_offline.htm file in the root directory.

No such file unfortunately.
I also don't think the app is being taken offline in any kind of deliberate manner. Seems more like an exception that can't be recovered from unless the App Service is restarted.

Did you try the deployment from your local machine? Does the issue exists when deploying from local? @altec

Seems like I can't reproduce the issue when deploying locally from PowerShell using New-AzResourceGroupDeployment . Do you think it could be related to the DevOps service connection?

You mentioned the issue occurs every 3 deployments. Try to execute the deployment multiplate times from local. Wen deploying form local, try to use the same service principal to login as that of the service connection. Ans use the same deployment parameters as possible.

Tested by deploying 4 times with personal credentials and same parameters.
I don't have access to the service principal credentials, though I'll note that down as something to investigate.
Appreciate the help!

Did you try the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 - Azure App Service deploy v4 task?

@BrightRan-MSFT I haven't, due to reproducing the issue being too time consuming, and I've observed the App Service and kudu becoming unavailable after only deploying the infrastructure. So I don't believe it's related to deploying the application (as an exception appears to have already occurred somewhere in the App Service, so either way Kudu won't respond).

The error code 50x generally is caused by the problem on the server side. Maybe, there is problem with your Azure Logic App service that caused the the error. @altec

We've come up with a workaround which is to restart the app service if it's a first-time deployment.
It's not ideal, though Microsoft didn't have any suggestions after an initial conversation.
We could investigate further, but like most developers we don't have unlimited time to be investigating, so have stopped our efforts here.
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: Check if first time deployment
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <subscription>
        scriptType: inlineScript
        inline: |
          $existing = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <rg-name> -Name <logic-app-name> -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          if($existing -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_FIRST_LOA_DEPLOYMENT]true"
          }
          else {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IS_FIRST_LOA_DEPLOYMENT]false"
          }
        azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"

    # App service will sometimes experience an exception here and Kudu will stop responding if being deployed into an environment for the first time
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: Deploy logic app infra
      inputs:
        deploymentScope: "Resource Group"
        azureResourceManagerConnection: <connection>
        subscriptionId: <subscriptionId> 
        action: "Create Or Update Resource Group"
        resourceGroupName: <rg-name>
        location: <location>
        templateLocation: "Linked artifact"
        csmFile: <your-arm-template>
        csmParametersFile: <parameter-file>
        deploymentMode: "Incremental"

    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: Restart Logic App
      condition: eq(variables.IS_FIRST_LOA_DEPLOYMENT, true)
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <subscription>
        scriptType: inlineScript
        inline: |
          Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <rg-name> -Name <logic-app-name>
        azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"

    # allow app service to come back online before attempting to deploy application
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: Delay 1 minute
      condition: eq(variables.IS_FIRST_LOA_DEPLOYMENT, true)
      inputs:                  
        azureSubscription: <subscription>
        scriptType: inlineScript
        azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"
        inline: |
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
            
    - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
      displayName: 'Deploying Standard Logic App'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <subscription>
        appType: 'functionApp'
        appName: <logic-app-name>
        package: <path-to-zip>
        deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'


I am able to deploy the Logic App ARM Template with ARM Template Deployment task and Logic App project (Function task too).
My ARM Template:-
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logicAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Logic App to create."
            }
        }

    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {
                        "Recurrence": {
                            "type": "Recurrence",
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Hour",
                                "interval": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}

Release pipeline:-


Output:-


My logic app FunctionAppDeployment task:-
Yaml code:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy files to artifact staging directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **/*.json
      !**/bin/**
      !**/obj/**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LogicApp'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy logic app workflows'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (0xxxxxxxxxa7)'
    appType: 'functionApp'
    appName: 'xxxxxxxx'
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact.zip'
    deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'

Output:-



Bit of an odd request, but can you try deleting that resource and deploying again (twice).
My problem is intermittent, so it fails about every third time.
I like the copy task by the way, nice way to make sure only the required files needed get deployed.

Also Microsoft.Logic/workflows is for consumption logic apps, not standard which like Function Apps use Microsoft.Web/sites to deploy an App Service.

@altec Can you refer this Project - https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/tree/master/azure-devops-sample For your Ci/Cd deployment of standard logic app

To rule out the possibility of a host ID collision (which can occur in Standard Logic Apps as well as in Function Apps), try adding the AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid app setting with a unique value.

The names of our resources are easily less than 32 characters, so I don't think this is likely to be the culprit. I'll give it a try at some stage though once I have time.

@altec I'm wondering if you found a solution to your issue.

No unfortunately. I've commented with our workaround.
